# AS3 - FLVPlayback component completion handler

Tags: actionscript-3, event-handling, flvplayback

I have an FLVPlayback component, instance named flvPlayer. The code below is in frame 1 of intro scene, which **works perfectly fine in Flash CS5** but not in CS6!
Obviously I want the video player to jump to the next scene when the video reaches the end.

```
import fl.video.*;

flvPlayer.source = "videos/1.flv";

flvPlayer.addEventListener(VideoEvent.COMPLETE, completeHandler);

function completeHandler(event:VideoEvent):void
{
    MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndPlay(1, "mainScene");
}
```

in CS6, it gives me this compile error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably, not the problem of CS5 or CS6, but the target runtime version of flash.

[VideoEvent.COMPLETE](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/video/VideoEvent.html) is defined in flash 10.1 & below.

Try using `Event.COMPLETE` instead of  `VideoEvent.COMPLETE` (From [this discussion](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?370085-VideoEvent-COMPLETE-is-not-working-in-cs5-5))

Comment: I had to change the 
function completeHandler(event:VideoEvent):void
to Event too.. :D

Answer (score 1):

I suspect a weird namespace issue with the latest CS6/Flash stuff. Try replacing all `VideoEvent` references with its full namespace `fl.video.VideoEvent`:

```
import fl.video.*;

flvPlayer.source = "videos/1.flv";

flvPlayer.addEventListener(fl.video.VideoEvent.COMPLETE, completeHandler);

function completeHandler(evt:fl.video.VideoEvent):void
{
    MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndPlay(1, "mainScene");
}
```

Comment: this fixed it, but the other answer provided by loxxy was right either and fixed the issue.